# Get field name in SQL query with DISTINCT and UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union, distinct

I have following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(uniq)
FROM
(
    SELECT sex AS uniq FROM type4
    UNION
    SELECT fason AS uniq FROM type4
    UNION
    SELECT color AS uniq FROM type4
    UNION
    SELECT size AS uniq FROM type4
) AS Temp
```

It works almost well, it returns:

```
[uniq] => some unique value
```

Is it possible to know which column this unique value was from?
I mean something like this:

```
[uniq] => some unique value
[from] => size
```

How can I do this?

Comment: And if a value is found in 2 or more columns, what should be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(uniq)
FROM
(
    SELECT (sex + ' 1') AS uniq FROM type4
    UNION
    SELECT (fason + ' 2') AS uniq FROM type4
    UNION
    SELECT (color + ' 3') AS uniq FROM type4
    UNION
    SELECT (size + ' 4') AS uniq FROM type4
) AS Temp
```

then you can use substring to remove the last 2 from right

Comment: What will `sex + '1'` show? Is this supposed to be string concatenation?

Comment: yes i tried it in ms sql you might have to add something in mysql to concatenate it..but in theory it should work.

Comment: `+` works as a concat operator only in SQL-Server (and in some programming languages like VB I think).

Comment: right that's what I am using I am pretty sure in mysql you need to add a CONCAT(sex, '1') and then you could still use the substring function to remove that "1"

Comment: This is probably the worst way to achieve what the OP asks, in matters of database performance. The engine has to first, concat all values from the 4 rows with the `' 1'` parts, then do a `UNION` of the 4 temp. tables which means sorting (without any possibility of using an index) of the temp tables to find duplicates. And the final wrapping with `DISTINCT` is useless at that point.

Comment: well unfortunatly I'm not a sql expert just sharing what i may know and sometimes it helps and sometimes it doesn't.  if this is a wrong method of doing it because of performance then you may be right, but the time it took me to come up with an idea that was the best i got.  he can choose any of the other answers..

Comment: Your answer is not wrong and it answers the question. It's just not going to be fast with a big table.

Answer (score 3):

Your original query does not need the subquery nor the `DISTINCT`. You could use:

```
SELECT sex AS uniq FROM type4
UNION
SELECT fason FROM type4
UNION
SELECT color FROM type4
UNION
SELECT size FROM type4
```

---

Now for your question, if the four columns have no overlapping values, you could use:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT sex AS uniq
                , 'sex' AS FromColumn 
  FROM type4
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT fason 
                , 'fason' 
  FROM type4
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT color 
                , 'color' 
  FROM type4
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT size 
                , 'size' 
  FROM type4
```